# Change ngModel value to switch tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sweetalert

I'm trying to change the `ngModel` value after a click on the `Cancel` button (`sweet alert`) to switch tab (`div` in `html` code) but it does not work.

This is the **HTML**:

```
<div ng-show="tabsMainMenu=='tabOne'">
   <h1>tabOne</h1>
</div>
<div ng-show="tabsMainMenu=='tabTwo'">
   <h1>tabTwo</h1>
</div>
```

And the **JS**:

```
 swal({
     title: 'Cancel?',
     text: 'Are you sure?',
     icon: 'warning',
     buttons: true
 })
 .then((cancel) => {
   if (cancel) {
   // Go back to Tab One 
   $scope.tabsMainMenu = 'tabOne';
   }
});
```

Only when I put the `mouse cursor` over the `Cancel` button on `html` page it's recognizes the new value of the `tabsMainMenu` `ngModel`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promises are normally async, so they're outside angular's lifecycle. That means angular doesn't know anything changed when your `.then` function runs. So, you just need to wrap the stuff inside your `.then` function in a `$scope.apply`.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply